# Remove newline literal characters from function returned value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which return a list with embedded literals like `\n`, `\r\n` etc. Any change to this function is beyond my control(its a 3rd party api). I can only get `rc` and `output` from the function. Can someone please help in converting the output of the function to un-escaped values ?

```
def my_funct():
    #some logic
    local_output = ['a','b\n','c\n','d',5,1]
    local_rc = 0
    return local_rc, local_output


rc, output = my_funct()

print(f"rc={rc}")
print(f"output={output}")

#    some failed attempts below but commented. 
#    print(f"output={(*output)}")
#    print(f"output={str(output).encode('unicode_escape').decode('utf-8')}")
```

Above code is helping in un-escaping the new lines literals.

Expected output of returned output outside of the function:

```
a b
c
d 5 1
```

Comment: Those values aren't escaped; the strings you show contain literal newline characters.

Comment: by un-escaping I meant, conversion of `\n` char to new line.

Comment: That *is* already a newline. `print('b\n')` prints a `b` and a newline.

Comment: I am novice to python, pardon my question but then why I am not getting desired output  as described in the question? what to do to get it ?

Comment: Maybe `local_output` is incorrect, and should actually return `['a', 'b\\n', 'c\\n', 'd', 5, 1}` but you can hardly ask us to troubleshoot code you didn't post.

Comment: The output from the `print` looks like that because you asked Python to `print` a list, and that's how it will format a list. Try `print(output[2])`

Answer (score 0):

you need to create translate table

```
trans_dict = {"\n": "", "\r": ""}
transtab = str.maketrans(trans_dict)
new_output = [str(x).translate(transtab) for x in local_output]
```